# Help creating Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a few problems that I have no clue how to solve though. How would I make each of the subsections have bullets instead of being numbered, also how would I change the sections to not being numbered at all? How would I change each of the page numbers that the sections and subsections reference to, like can I hard code it in? One last thing, is it possible to change the numbering at the bottom of the page to roman numerals?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Client Details}
\section{Team Details}
\subsection{Organization Details and Role Designation}
\subsection{Role Expectations}
\subsection{Decision-making Scheme}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well I am trying to merge this with another pdf later....that was not created in latex. So I have to do these things in order for it to be relevant to my project content.

Comment: I really think this project misconceived. If the content is not in LaTeX, there is not much to be said for using LaTeX to produce the ToC. The beauty of that system is precisely that you do ***not*** hard code it. And it looks good because it matches the style of the rest of the document. It will not look nearly so good if it does not match. So you have to worry about matching margins, fonts, line spacing, interword spacing, font sizes, footer etc. If the document is a Word document, just produce the ToC in Word. At least it will match. Consistency is a big part of the quality of LaTeX output.

Comment: @Panphobia Should the bullet appear also in the table of contents?

Comment: @egreg yeah it should appear instead of the 2.1/2.2 etc etc

Comment: @cfr well I totally agree with you, but having 4 group members who don't know latex can kind of make that difficult.

Comment: Not really. My point is that it doesn't make sense to use LaTeX only for the ToC. If you need to work in something else, work in something else.

Answer (score 6):

I'll change the `\@seccntformat` so that one can set independently what's printed when a sectional title is asked for.

Also `\l@subsection` needs to be changed, together with `\thesubsection`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname format@#1\endcsname
    \csname format@#1\endcsname
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\format@section}{\thesection\quad}
\newcommand{\format@subsection}{\textbullet\ }
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\textbullet}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.4em}{1em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Client Details}
\section{Team Details}
\subsection{Organization Details and Role Designation}
\subsection{Role Expectations}
\subsection{Decision-making Scheme}

\end{document}
```

### Page 1

[image]

### Page 2

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a quick hack, redefining `\@sect` partially (no more time right now) -- it does not address page number issues etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}


\makeatletter


\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{subsection}{% is it a `\subsection`
      \protected@edef\@svsec{\protect\phantom{\csname the#1\endcsname.}\textbullet\quad\relax}%
      }{%   Nope, a normal section
        \protected@edef\@svsec{\relax} % do nothing 
        %\protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
      }%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{subsection}{%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
         \protect\numberline{\textbullet}% Use `\textbullet in the toc
        \fi
        #7}}{%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        % \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}% drop the number line entry 
      \fi
      #7
      }%
    }%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}


\makeatother
\begin{document}

%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\textbullet}


\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Client Details}
\section{Team Details}
\subsection{Organization Details and Role Designation}
\subsection{Role Expectations}
\subsection{Decision-making Scheme}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I understand the following:

If all the other group members work in Word, then you should probably work in Word, too. If the other members use Word consistently (i.e. apply styles to headings), then you would have no hard time creating a table of contents there, and you can make it look as good as you wish by also applying Word styles (the TOC is hardly the most difficult part of a document to format nicely!).

As another solution, you could transfer the content of the Word document in a LaTeX document in order to take advantage of LaTeX's automation.

But trying to create a TOC by hand (I am talking mostly about hard-coding page numbers) is really the worst of both worlds!

Comment: Though this is good aadvice, i don't think it answers the question.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I agree, but it was too long for a comment.